# Why would a Jest test suite fail randomly?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I have a NestJS application with various unit tests written using Jest.

The problem I am facing is that Jest is giving me very inconsistent results. If I run an individual test suite, it might pass, but sometimes it will fail. Likewise, when I run all my tests, sometimes they will all pass, and sometimes one or two suites will fail.

In each of the test suites, a MongoDB Memory Server is setup in the `beforeAll` hook and cleared up in the `afterAll` hook. When the all the suites are ran, they are done so with the `--runInBand` argument. Using the `no-cache` argument also does not help.

Can anyone point me towards what is going on here? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try change all `beforeAll` to `beforeEach`, and `afterAll` to `afterEach` when it make sense

Comment: Alright, I will experiment with this!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is usually hard to solve. It's hard to diagnose without project knowledge, but I would suspect race condition of any sort.
Sometimes it might be related to problems with test setup/cleanup or tests depending on each other. But in this case it would not reproduce while running the single test.
So make sure to check all asynchronous related code. Make sure there is explicit order of all dependent tasks, and there is no assumptions about order of execution.
You can test it by adding logs everywhere and run test until it fails. Then compare logs for successful/failed runs.

Comment: I have ESLint set up in the project and ran it to check for any mishandled Promises and it did not report any errors in the project. I'll add logs and see if that yields anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses Алексей and Micael. I was able to figure out what was wrong with the tests.

After running each of the test suites both individually and all together, my team was able to identify the issue. It was always two particular test suites that were failing. Both of them used a service that was dealing with random data and there was a case that was not handled appropriately. And the failing tests were assuming that this scenario would not occur. But when it did pop up, the corresponding test(s) would fail.